# Передача информации из component в app.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите , при клике по кнопке которая находится в компоненте должен меняться state  в app.vue ... Как реализовать ?

Comment: $emit, в крайнем случае через стор

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85